# Can we burninate the [errors] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I don't think the [errors](/questions/tagged/errors) tag can stand on its own or adds any relevant information to a question, so I suggest burninating it.

[image: Calling Trogdor]

Comment: There's 32 instances, it can be removed manually.

Comment: Sure. I just love the image, and I can't post it without the word "burninate", can I?

Comment: Can the 3-day-old tag wiki also be removed?

Comment: The tag wiki will disappear when the tag disappears, which happens within a day or so of it no longer being attached to any questions.

Comment: Speaking of, it's now been cleaned out, with at least a few others helping.

Comment: Oh, wow, that was fast. A couple of minutes ago, there were still 20ish, I got distracted and read a meta post, and it's all done :D

Comment: Perhaps `errors` should be a tag blacklist candidate?